# Howto vectorize a Bitmap-file with the Inkscape 1.0+ cli interface?

Tags: inkscape

I want to vectorize a jpg line drawing with the inkscape inbuilt autotrace -centerline option. I found these actions verbs:

```
--verbs=
FileImport
SelectionTrace

--actions=
select-all
all
```

so I think this shoud be possible with Inkcape 1.+ cli ui. But how exactly? Thanks!

Comment: Not possible yet. Use 0.92.x's centerline tracing extension on the command line: https://github.com/fablabnbg/inkscape-centerline-trace (also requires Inkscape 0.92.x's inkex) or use autotrace directly. I think the package was taken out of Ubuntu, though, for security reasons, so be aware it might not be safe for running with user-provided data.

Comment: @Moini Not in version 0.92, but in versions 1.0+ it should be possible

Comment: No. It's not possible yet. This requires the dialog to be controllable parametrically from the command line, which it is not yet in Inkscape 1.0. it can be opened, but that's all.